# Dapper > Parameterless Constructor

Tags: c#, dapper

This is my Object:

```
public class Ticket
    {
        public Ticket(string origin, string destination, string price, DateTime travelDate)
        {
            Origin = origin;
            Destination = destination;
            Price = price;
            TravelDate = travelDate;
        }
        public string Origin { get; private set; }
        public string Destination { get; private set; }
        public string Price { get; private set; }
        public DateTime TravelDate { get; private set; }
    }
```

This is my Post:

```
public class AddTicketRepository : IAddTicketRepository
    {
        private readonly IDbContext _dbContext;

        public AddTicketRepository(IDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        public void AddTicket(Ticket ticket)
        {
            var query = "INSERT INTO ticket(origin, destination, price, date) VALUES(@origin, @destination, @price, @date)";

            var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
            parameters.Add("origin", ticket.Origin, System.Data.DbType.String);
            parameters.Add("destination", ticket.Destination, System.Data.DbType.String);
            parameters.Add("price", ticket.Price, System.Data.DbType.Decimal);
            parameters.Add("date", ticket.TravelDate, System.Data.DbType.DateTime);

            using var connection = _dbContext.CreateConnection();

            connection.Execute(query, parameters);
        }
    }
```

Works fine !

Then I started creating my HTTPGET to get all tickets from Database:

first my Interface:

```
public interface IGetTicketsRepository
    {
        List<Ticket> GetTickets();
    }
```

```
public class GetTicketsRepository : IGetTicketsRepository
    {
        private readonly IDbContext _dbContext;

        public GetTicketsRepository(IDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        public List<Ticket> GetTickets()
        {
            var query = "SELECT * FROM ticket";

            using var connection = _dbContext.CreateConnection();

            var tickets = connection.Query<Ticket>(query).ToList();

            return tickets;
        }
    }
```

When executing the swagger GET I get the following message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A parameterless default constructor
> or one matching signature (System.Int32 Id, System.String origin,
> System.String destination, System.Double price, System.DateTime date)
> is required for Domain.Entities.Ticket materialization'

I really don't have a clue what I'm doing wrong.

Tried finding articles about this exception but nothing clear

Comment: This definitely solved my problem, I just added the parameterless class and it worked, good tip about not using * thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, the problem is that it can't find a constructor that matches the results - the results have an `Id` that the constructor lacks

Two solutions:

1. Add a parameterless constructor - it can be private, `private Ticket() {}`
2. *Change the query* to not include the `Id` that you don't want: `"SELECT Origin, Destination, Price, TravelDate FROM ticket"`

Note: Using `*` in real queries (outside of exploring the DB) is usually a bad idea, as:

1. the order of columns is undefined (and can depend on whether a DB is new or upgraded), and
2. you can end up returning *lots* of data that is not wanted - either lots of columns, or just a single column with a very large blob/clob payload.